# Passing more than 1 form field

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I'm trying to update the LastName field for PersonID.  I can pass PersonID, but I don't know the syntax for also passing the LastName field.

```
$('input[name="LastName"]').live('focusout', function() {
    var PersonID = $(this).parents("tr").attr("ID");
    var LastName = $(this).val(); // todo: serialize
    $.ajax({
        url:'Remote/Person.cfc?method=UpdateLastName&returnformat=json'
        ,data:'PersonID='+PersonID
    });
    $(this).parents("td").empty().append(LastName);
});
```

Q: Is is something like data:{'PersonID='+PersonID,'LastName='+LastName}

Am I missing a squiggly line or a parenthesis or comma or dot or colon or semi-colon or plus sign or question mark or an apostrophe or quote or dollar sign or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're close!  Change it just a little, no equals in there and use a colon like this:

```
data: {'PersonID':PersonID, 'LastName':LastName}
```

You can also do this if you prefer (not as safe if you get some weird characters though)

```
data: 'PersonID=' + PersonID + '&LastName=' + LastName
```

Comment: OMG.  OK, now for my next question: Do you know how much I love stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

For complicated structures in case you add more then 2 vars:

```
var obj = new Object;
obj.something1 = 'something';
obj.something2 = Array();
obj.something2[1] = 'foo';
obj.something2[2] = 'bar';

//include json2.js
var objJSON =  JSON.stringify(obj);

$.ajax({
      url: "http://example.com",
      type: "GET",
      data: ({obj: objJSON , method : "UpdateLastName"}),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(msg){
         alert("Success: " + msg);
      },
      error: function(msg){
         alert("Error: " + msg);
      }
    });
```

On cf side just do

```
<cfset test = deserializeJSON(arguments.obj,true) >
```

Comment: Wow zharcos, this is a fantastic answer!

Comment: I thought I might help so I decided to give back to community :) 
Changed nick to this one. twitter.com/zarkosusnjar